Are there words with two shwas in a row?
I think a (syllable with a) shwa never follows another (syllable with a) shwa in English. Is it true for all the words? And, more generally, is it true for every sentence? For example, is it ever possible that "of that" in the sentence "I want to get rid of that" be pronounced /ə(v) ðət/?

In "I want to get rid of that", the word is emphasised - "that thing there" - so it would not be pronounced with a shwa as in "the one that I brought with me".

There's something I want to get rid of that I can't precisely enunciate. It's perfectly possible to enunciate that with schwas for the two consecutive highlighted words. Or This is the one that a lot of people would quite naturally enunciate as two consecutive schwas. There's nothing special about that particular sequence of "reduced vowels" in English, even if we're naturaly inclined to read bold text as fully-enunciated / stressed vowels.

I’m voting to close this question because it's based on a random idea that has no relevance to natural use of English. Just because not all pairs of consecutive words in all contexts can be reduced to schwas doesn't mean any two words can't be a pair of consecutive schwas in some contexts.

Uh-uh. maybe not. Or perhaps there's a hot answer here: https://www.britannica.com/science/aa-lava-flow Alos, hear https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cmjrTcYMqBM

"There's a sofa around here" has two consecutive schwas without an intervening consonant.  Unless you reduce around to 'round.

There are many words where schwa occurs in two adjacent syllables (usually with at least one consonant in between the vowels). Two examples are riotous and exodus.
Since schwa is a "weak" vowel, words that contain schwa often have variant pronunciations. For example, when schwa comes before a sonorant consonant (/ɹ, l, m, n/), a syllabic consonant can often be used instead. Or in some cases, schwa can be dropped entirely (called syncope), making a word have one less syllable. An example is camera, which could be three syllables ending ni in [-məɹə] or [-mɹ̩ə], but could also be two syllables ending in [mɹə]. Some speakers also don't make a clear distinction between schwa and the vowel /ɪ/ in certain kinds of unstressed syllables.
